# Package is not specified in the manifest file

Tags: android, android-layout

While trying to create and Extract string from the layout file it is showing the alert dialog that Package is not specified in the manifest file. It is happening from while I had updated my studio to the newest version(chimpunk 2021.2.1) and the newest gradle(7.2). any help will be appretiated.

Comment: In newer Chipmunk update PackageName is moved in build.gradle file. Please upgrade Android Studio's grandle plugin to 7.3 and Gradle binaries to 7.3.3+, then tray again

Comment: I'm currently running 7.3.3 and it is still occurring. There is an open (as of this comment) [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232060575) for Android Studio's Upgrade Assistant. Sounds like this might get fixed in a point release. In the meantime adding package back in the manifest works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem. Open AndroidManifest.xml and add your package name back.

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"> <!--This is what I added-->
```

Comment: Why not `android:package="..."`?  This is so inconsistent!

Comment: It seems "package" is its own attribute not belonging to the Android namespace. I looked it up on Android's developer website and that's how it's listed: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element